# Reloading Content of Ajax Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm completely puzzled, I make an ajax call inside a Jquery UI Tab, after that I want to refresh the content of the tab, the function that should be doing it is:

```
function reloadTab(){
var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
$tabs.tabs('load', selected);
return false; 
}
```

Incredible but true it doesn't work at all, since this:

```
$tabs.tabs('select', selected);
```

Wouldn't work either I thought it was an issue with not being able to reload a tab, and this is what I found out:

'select' works only to select a different tab than the current one while load doesn't work at all.

I also tried the solution posted here: [Stuck reloading ajax content in a jQuery Tab programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900821/stuck-reloading-ajax-content-in-a-jquery-tab-programatically)

With no luck.. please help me because I'm starting to get angry :-(

Answer (score 1):

Could you please clarify: Does selected contain the expected value, i.e. does

```
$tabs.tabs('option', 'selected')
```

produce the correct index? If it does, then `tabs('load')` appears to be buggy (as suggested in the post you mentioned). Maybe you could try switching to another tab, do the load, then switch back again. Not very elegant, I know. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Yes, it contains the expected value (2) I also tried to call it like this: $tabs.tabs('load',2); with no luck.

I finally given up and made a 'manual' ajax call to reload the page. The tabs part of jquery is surprisingly buggy.

Thank you anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
function reloadTab(tabnum) {
 $('#tabs').tabs('select',tabnum);
 $('#tabs').tabs('load',tabnum);
}
```

The trick is that load does not work if there hasn't been a tab selected first.